# Markov Process graphical representation

Tags: statistics, markov-process

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how the picture has been constructed. Specifically how $\mu^{11}=-(\mu^{12}+\mu^{13}+\mu^{14})$ and $\mu^{44}=-\mu^{43}$ has been graphically represented. Here $\mu^{ij}$ is the rate at which we change from state $i$ to state $j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu^{ij}$ is nonzero, it means that there is nonzero probability that a transition occurs from state $i$ to state $j$. Each of the states is represented by a vertex in the graph (in the picture, each vertex is drawn as a box). In your example, there are four states ($G$ is a $4\times4$ matrix). Each nonzero $\mu^{ij}$ is represented as a weighted edge in the graph from $i$ to $j$ with weight $\mu^{ij}$.

The elements $\mu^{11}$ and $\mu^{44}$ are not represented in the graph. This is because the diagonal entries are there only to make $G$ a generator matrix and correspond to no transition rate from one state to another. <s>However, some texts display the adjacency graph of $G$, in which diagonal entries are represented as loops (e.g., an edge from $1$ to itself).</s>

Comment: Loops would be offtopic here since $\mu^{ii}<0$.

Comment: @Did: Some texts display the (directed) adjacency graph for the matrix $A$, in which there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ whenever $a_{ij}\neq 0$.

Comment: But here the entries $\mu^{ij}\geqslant0$ for $i\ne j$ are *transition rates* while the diagonal entries $\mu^{ii}<0$ are there only to make the whole a generator matrix and correspond to no transition rate from one state to another.

Comment: @Did: I have added your comment in the answer to clarify things.

Comment: Actually I now understand where your confusion lies: you are taking generator matrices for adjacency matrices. These are (related but) different notions.

Comment: I am not confused. The (directed) adjacency graph of a generator matrix is a useful concept. Shameless self-link to my own paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03928.pdf. See Definition 3.1 and Example 4.2. While the matrix considered is not a generator matrix, it has the same sparsity structure as the corresponding generator matrix.

Comment: ?? Useful in general yes, but in the present case, not to be confused with the generator matrix. Hence mentioning the former à propos the latter is, sorry to add, misleading.

Comment: Anyways, I have removed it. Let's agree that I am not confused, and took a suboptimal approach to teaching the topic in my answer.